# PHP get value from key value pair

Tags: php, key

I have a key-value pair from which I would like to retrieve the value and since it's part of a loop, the key is dynamic and I can't call the value by its key name.

I know that if i have

```
array (size=1)
   '2004-01-07 12:00' => string '12:00 pm 1:30 pm' (length=16)
```

If I use `key($array)` I can get the key. Is there an similar function or method to find the value? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there always is going to be 1 item in the array - or you always need the first or last element - you can get it with a number of array functions.

For example:

```
reset($array)    // get the value of the first element
end($array)      // get the value of the last element
current($array)  // get the value of the current element
// etc.
```

Answer (score 4):

In a loop you can define the keys.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  echo $key;
  echo $value;
}
```